# Combining map with split

Tags: swift, string, swift3, casting

From having following string: `12#17#15` I want to get an array with the numbers: `[12, 17, 15]`.

I've tried following approach, but firstly I still get an error (`Cannot convert value of type '[Double?]' to expected argument type 'Double?'`), and obviously, I prefer to do it all on one map instead of such chain. Why do these types differ..? I'd say they should be matching...

```
let substrings = records?.split(separator: "#", maxSplits: Int.max, omittingEmptySubsequences: true).map(String.init).map(Double.init)
let objects = substrings.map {value in Model(value: value ?? 0)}
```

Comment: why can't you just do `yourString.components(separatedBy: "#")` or am I not understanding what you want to do?

Comment: I dont see any error with your code. Could you check again ?

Comment: `let objects = (records ?? "").split(separator: "#").map(Double.init).map(Model.init)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't like this solution because you're mapping (iterating) 2 times. Better to extend MacLean answer: `string.split(separator: "#").map(){Model(value: Double($0) ?? 0)}`

Comment: @Vive yes iterating only once it is better. Note that value expects an optional Double so nil coalescing it is not needed. `let objects = (records ?? "").split(separator: "#").flatMap{Model(value: Double($0))}`

Comment: Btw don't make your object value property an optional if it really can't be nil.

Comment: also you could just use map in this case `let objects = (records ?? "").split(separator: "#").map{Model(value: Double($0))}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's some technique I've never heard of, you're not using `map` correctly.

Here's an example of the code you want:

```
let string = "12#17#15"
let objects = string.split(separator: "#").map {Double($0) ?? 0}
```

in Swift, `map` does something to every entry of an array, and then results in some sort of output. What's going on here is that first just doing a simple split (I'm going to assume you don't actually need the upper limit of an Int for the max results, but you can re-add that if you wish), and then initing a `Double` with each substring (which you call with `$0`). If trying to create that `Double` fails, then I'm coalescing it to a 0 instead of a `nil`.

If you don't want the `Double`s that fail and return `nil` to be zero, then use `flatmap {$0}` instead

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer, I've casted this to my object and everything works properly. My mistake I didn't remove those default parameters (in the real app the parameters are not default, changed for SOF without thinking).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `flatMap` instead of `map`, as Double init with String can return optional.

```
let records = "12#17#15"
let substrings = records.split(separator: "#").flatMap {Double($0)}
print(substrings) // [12.0, 17.0, 15.0]
```